How to configure ECS(FARGATE) + ALB with gRPC
I am developing an API in quarkus (java-21) with gRPC.
The endpoints in the local environment worked perfectly, but I am having problems when I publish to AWS.
In AWS I am using ECS ​​with FARGATE and ALB, in addition to having configured aws cloud map, with this DNS within the private VPC I was able to access the gRPC endpoints, so I believe the problem is in the ALB settings.
Quarkus settings
Both gRPC and REST are configured on the same port 8096
(ECS) Service settings


(ECS) Task settings

ALB settings

Test performed with aws cloud map DNS, using grpcurl

The target group related to the service has HTTP1. I've already done some tests switching to gRPC but it didn't work.
Do you need more information to help me?

Did you try setting the target group to HTTP2? The HTTP1 setting will definitely not work for gRPC. The HTTP2 setting says it supports both HTTP2 and gRPC without specific gRPC features.  Since you are doing both REST (HTTP) and gRPC on the same port, I think HTTP2 is the only target group protocol you could use. Otherwise you may need to configure REST and gRPC to be on different ports, and configure two target groups for the different protocols.
